# Missing a lot of options from Finder's right click context menu

Tags: macos, finder, ui, contextual-menu

No idea what caused this or why it's happening, but when I right click something in Finder  I'm missing a lot of the standard options that should be there (dropbox options, labels, etc). I've restarted several times, relaunched Finder, repaired disk permissions, and nothing's worked.

When I right click on my Desktop:

[image: When I right click on my Desktop]

When I right click a file in Finder:

[image: When I right click a file in Finder]

Comment: Test this behavior in another user account. The guest account will suffice. Does it still occur?

Comment: I only have my one account on this computer, but I enabled the guest account and logged in. Everything seemed to be working normally there.

Comment: From the Finder Menu Bar (in your user account) > Go... > Go To Folder > ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist  **delete** the file, log out, and log back in. Any difference?

Comment: Just tried deleting that file and logged out, still having the same issue.

Comment: Reboot in **Safe Mode.** Log in. Same issue?

Comment: Booted into Safe Mode and everything was working normally (no issue). Booted back into "regular" mode and everything is working fine there too. Doesn't explain what exactly fixed the issue though... I've had it happen a few times before and it fixed itself, I only asked about it this time to see if I could permanently fix it somehow.

Comment: Scratch that. Now it's not working, and I haven't logged out or rebooted since it was working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14654/discussion-between-njboot-and-will-ryan).

Comment: I looked at your  etrecheck feed. You have a ton of user specific launchagents, launchdaemons, and login items. I can't identify a specific culprit, but it makes sense given 1) it doesn't occur in another account and 2) it doesn't occur in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it looks like your Dropbox is misbehaving.

Do you have the latest version of Dropbox? Reinstall Dropbox with the newest version.

> Dropbox uses a "hack" which extends the Finder (in an unsupported way) to provide this "sharing" link.  Because these "hacks" can cause crashes, Apple tends to disable them when newer versions of OS X ship. There's probably a newer version of DropBox that gets around these restrictions that you'll need to download.

<sup>Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5577081</sup>

Comment: Reinstalled dropbox, rebooted, still had the issue. Then I followed someone's suggestion above to boot into safe mode to see if the issue was present there. It wasn't, then I booted back into OSX regularly and for some reason the issue wasn't present there either. No idea what fixed it or if it'll continue...

Comment: Scratch that, not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Will, are you using [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/)? I had the same problem and it was caused by [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/). Upgrading to version 1.6 solved it.

Comment: ^ TotalFinder was causing this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Quit dropbox.
2. Terminal:

> $ sudo rm -rf /Library/DropboxHelperTools

3. Terminal:

> $ killall finder

4. Open Dropbox.
5. Enter Admin PWD when prompted. (Good Signal)

Win.

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly had the same problem of no dropbox options in right click menu, no possibility to directly attach a file to Mail app. I downloaded and installed my macOS from the  App Store. At the end my files and apps were not modified and Dropbox options and Mail app restarted to work properly